# Windows 7 says its not a genuine copy as its been installed on multiple machines (although they machines are wiped first)

Tags: windows-7, windows, parallels, serial-number

I have Windows 7 installed on my macbook pro via Parallels virtual machine.

Since buying the copy of windows 7 (about 5 years ago) Ive wiped and re installed the OS on my laptop. Each time i dont port over the parallels data and have just re installed parallels and windows 7. This is causing an issue where windows says that the copy of windows 7 may not be genuine (as from its point of view it thinks its been installed 3 times (although the device its on gets wiped each time before it installed on a new device)

Any ideas how i can revoke the installs on these now wiped machines so Window 7 will think its only installed with this license key on my current machine ?

Answer (score 1):

On your Windows 7 install, go to "Activate Windows", you can try "Activate over the phone"(can't remember exact message), but it will give you a number to call, and an installation ID.

You will put that installation ID, and then you will either get a robot voice prompt asking "how many computers is it installed on", or you'll be transferred to a real person.

If you get the real person, just tell them what you have done, and that this license of Windows is only on "One" computer.

If you get the robot voice, just tell it one computer and it should let you through.

Unless your license is an OEM copy, where it's only valid on the computer it was installed on, you should be fine.

Comment: I have even had the robot activate me after saying "one" I think if it is the first time calling for a key they may be more lenient and just let the automated system handle it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've had the same result.  Most times I get the robot, but sometimes I get a person.

Answer (score -1):

Next time, you should deactivate your Windows 7 before  wipe and re-install OS.

Follow this link to 
[How to deactivate and uninstall Windows Product Key](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/deactivate-uninstall-windows-product-key)

To solve your activation process please follow the instruction at this link,
[Submit a genuine Windows technical support request](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ID/windows/help/genuine/submit-request)

Comment: Why does this answer just contain links.  There are only a couple required steps.